# How to pass database name as a parameter to sql statement in python?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have different sql statements(create, insert,delete, update,...) in python that I want to execute them for different databases,and I want to pass database name as a parameter to sql statements.
example:
query = """
         SELECT * 
         FROM [mainDB].[dbo].[customer]
        """

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM ' + databaseName`

Comment: Replace `[mainDB]` with a variable name => `query = "SELECT * FROM "+ dataBaseName +".[dbo].[customer] "`

Answer (score 1):

you should replace `[mainDB]` with a variable name in your query => `"SELECT * FROM "+ dataBaseName +".[dbo].[customer] "`

You can set a list of database name and loop on this list to perform your query

```
for i, dbName in enumerate(['mydb', 'otherdb', 'thirddb']):
     print("SELECT * FROM ["+ dbName +"].[dbo].[customer];")
```