# Pass database name variable in SQL query using Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

My config file has database details like below:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()            
config.read("C:/configsql.ini")
_SERVER_NAME = config['SQL']['SERVER_NAME']
_DATABASE = config['SQL']['DATABASE']
_USERNAME = config['SQL']['USERNAME']
_PASSWORD = config['SQL']['PASSWORD']
```

How do I utilize `_DATABASE` variable in my SQL Queries which are executed via python. Currently, SQL queries are hardcoded with database name - `TEST`.

Below are two types of SQL Queries used in my python code:

```
connsql = self.sql_connection()
query = "select distinct top 2 filing_id, StatusIndicator from [TEST].[dbo].[FILE] where ID = ?"  
resultset = connsql.cursor().execute(query,values).fetchall()
connsql.cursor().commit()
connsql.close()
```

And,

```
query ='''
        IF EXISTS(select [file_name], [file] from [TEST].[dbo].[FILE] where ID = ? and TypeID = 1)
        BEGIN 
            select [file_name], [file] from [TEST].[dbo].[FILE] where ID = ? and TypeID = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SELECT - 1
        END                   
      '''
values = (Id,Id)
results = connsql.cursor().execute(query, values).fetchall()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass database name as a parameter to sql statement in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676077/how-to-pass-database-name-as-a-parameter-to-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: The approach works for my first query format where `query =" "` But, how to make it work for second query format where it has 3 quotes `query ='''   '''`

Comment: The solution linked by @sugar2code should only be used where you're not accepting user input as database name - it's wide open to injection.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I utilize _DATABASE variable in my SQL Queries which are executed via python.

You should normally specify the database in your `sql_connection`, so you can use 2-part names instead of 3-part names in your queries.